# Hour:Minute presentation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create table with every minute time presentation.
There will be three fields

TIME_DESC Values : 00:00, 00:01,... , 12:32, 12:33,... ,23:58, 23:59 (according to hours and minutes)
Hour Values: 00-23 (according to hours)
Minute Values: 00-59 (according to Minutes)

So, single record will look like || 01:05 || 01 || 05 || or || 22:25 || 22 || 25 ||

How can i implement this table creation in single Oracle query?

Thanks.

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: As the HOUR and MINUTE values are derivable from the TIME_DESC values why do you need three columns?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with:

```
select to_char(hr, '00')||':'||to_char(mi, '00') as time_desc,
       to_char(hr, '00') as hours, to_char(mi, '00') as minutes
from (select level-1 from dual connect by level <= 24) as hr cross join
     (select level-1 from dual connect by level <= 60) as mi
```

The trick here is to generate the numbers from 0 to 23 and 0 to 59.  The rest is just formatting these the way you want them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT to_date('0001-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + interval '1' MINUTE * (LEVEL-1) datetime
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1440
)
SELECT to_char(t.datetime, 'hh24:mi') time,
       to_char(t.datetime, 'hh24') hh,
       to_char(t.datetime, 'mi') mi
FROM t
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/1378) is a fiddle

Comment: Tip: `interval '1' MINUTE * (LEVEL-1)` equals `numtodsinterval(level-1,'minute')`

Comment: Thanks @RobvanWijk, actually I could also do `+ (level-1)/1440`

Comment: Which -to my mind- is shorter but less clear than numtodsinterval